# How to iterate a select_list from Page Objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, iteration, selectlist, page-object-gem

I have a page object that has a list item of locations.

```
select_list(:locations, :id => 'locations)
```

And I would like to have a list of locations and then select one of them.
Something like:

```
def select_item_different_than d_item    
 list_items = :locations.items #This is wrong, but you get the point
 list_items.each do |item|
   if item != d_item
     item.select
     return
   end
 end
end
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please, edit with example and expected result, it will help people to help you.

Comment: Done!I think it's clearer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select list elements have an `options` method that returns an array of its option elements. You could iterate over the array and compare them to the `d_item`.

The method could be:

```
def select_item_different_than d_item    
  list_items = locations_element.options
  list_items.each do |item|
    if item.text != d_item
      item.click
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the following changes were required:

1. The select list element is retrieved by `locations_element` instead of `:locations`.
2. The list of options is retrieved by `options` instead of `items`.
3. In the if statement `item != d_item` was changed to `item.text != d_item`. My assumption is that you want to compare the option's text and `d_item` is a string.
4. Option elements do not have a `select` method. Instead, use the `click` method.

Personally, I think the method might be more clear as:

```
def select_item_different_than d_item    
  locations_element
    .options
    .find{ |option| option.text != d_item }
    .click
end
```